# Red square rendering instead of the AwesomeFont Icon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-awesome

I was following this github : https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons to learn how to put some icon on my app ! So i did all they said :

-include in `android/setting.gradle`and `android/app/build.gradle` the differents parts of code.

-do the `register module (in MainActivity.java)`, the import in my corresponding MainActivity.Java

-`Copy the font files and .json` in the directory assets that i just create...

Paste the onCreate in my MainActivity.java with the references `.addPackage(new ReactNativeIcons(Arrays.asList(
                        new IconFont("typicons", "typicons.ttf")`

And so do my call `<Icon
                    name='typicons|beer'
                    size={150}
                    color='#887700'
                    style={styles.beer}/>`

with this styles

`beer: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            margin: 5,
            color: '#887700'
        },`

But my app display just a red square at this emplacement. Just the borders are red, and the inside is white...  I have no errors. So did i forgot something ? 
If you have any ideas to help me ! :) It's very strange :/

Thank's !

Comment: As far as I know, that lib is not longer maintaned. I tried to use them on my project, and I had the same problem. When I was looking around for answer, I read react-native-icons are no longer maintained, so I started to use react-native-vector-icons https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons and I don't have any problems with them (for now) :)

Comment: I just saw that, it's maybe the cause... :/ Sad ! Yes i was looking now react-native-vector-icons , and i try to use it ! And it doesn't looks like more difficult than react-native-icon... So we will see :) Thank's for answer !

Comment: @Vikky We are agree, that I just have to do `npm install react-native-icons@latest --save` and copy the contents of Fonts to app/src/main/assets/fonts .And for example to use it : `var Icon = require('react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome')` then `<Icon.Button name="facebook" backgroundColor="#3b5998" onPress={this.loginWithFacebook}>
                    Login with Facebook
                </Icon.Button>` ....<p> because this, doesn't work... :/

Comment: You have to do `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`, and after that `rnpm link` + I also had to copy the contents in the Fonts folder to android/app/src/main/assets/fonts (note lowercase font folder). And then I used it like this `var Icon = require('react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome');
var myIcon = (<Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />)` and ofc called it inside of renderer with `{myIcon}` . I tried Icon.Button and it works for me, I'll paste you code in next comment

Comment: Shorter version of code: 
`import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

const myIcon = (<Icon name="pencil-square-o" size={18} color="#F5FCFF"/>);

class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        var myButton = (
            <Icon.Button name="facebook" backgroundColor="#3b5998" onPress={this.loginWithFacebook}>
                Login with Facebook
            </Icon.Button>
        );
        return (
                    <View>
                        <Text>{myIcon} To Do</Text>{myButton}
                    </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;`

Comment: It doesn't work.... Don't undersand why !? The fonts (Entypo.ttf, AwesomeFont.ttf,...) inside the fonts folder have to be lowercase too ? I tried all ! Done 'npm instal...' then rnpm link, ... and follow youre example, doesn't working... :(

Comment: Here is my example project https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8wcyurz2ai7094/TodoTest.7z?dl=0 where I use react-native-vector-icons -> you can see usage in Navbar.js and that I pasted fontAwesome to my android/app/src/main/assets/fonts folder.I think for project to work on android it's enough just to npm install, here's pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GMTLM.jpg + no, you just have to copy fonts, you don't have to rename/lowercase .json and .otf (etc) files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new in react-native framework... And I didn't know that I will had to do "react-native run-android" . I thought that doing "rnpm link"... and "reload JS" will make the update of the new node_module....

So I re-install my app with "react-native run-android" which take in parameter the new node_module... And it work's now ! thank's @Vikky ! And I will know that, for the next time :p